# why cant you use both parts of the register in 32/64 bit x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, x86-16

in 16 bit assembly you can use a 16 bit register like or use one of the 2 8 bit registers that comprise it why can you only use the high memory addresses in 32 and 64 bit assembly ?

Comment: [Why can I access lower dword/word/byte in a register but not higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45500399/995714)

Comment: Because the architecture has not been designed to allow this.

Comment: arent ah and al sudo registers ? im pretty sure this is related to the assembly not the hardware